# VB.NET Program is always reading last created textfile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Trying to create a login form,

My coding is currently:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmLogin

    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim fileReader As String
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim files As Integer
    Dim filepath As String

    Public Structure info
        Dim U As String
        Dim P As String
    End Structure

    Dim details As info

    Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

        If txtusername.Text = details.U And txtpassword.Text = details.P Then
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
            frmmenu.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("wrong")
            txtusername.Clear()
            txtpassword.Clear()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btncreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncreate.Click
        frmcreate.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        files = files + 1
        filepath = "C:\Users\TheGlove\Desktop\Alex's Program\loginfile" & files & ".txt"
        Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\TheGlove\Desktop\Alex's Program")
        folderpath = "C:\Users\TheGlove\Desktop\Alex's Program"
        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderpath, "*.txt").Count

        For Each fi In di.GetFiles()

            MsgBox(fi.Name)
            Dim FILE = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\TheGlove\Desktop\Alex's Program\loginfile" & files & ".txt")
            Dim myArray As String() = FILE
            details.U = myArray(0)
            details.P = myArray(1)

        Next
    End Sub


End Class
```

Button 1 will be merged with btnlogin when i get it working and for now is currently just a seperate button to read each textfile.
When each button is pressed (Button 1 -> btnlogin), only the last created textfile is correct.

Comment: With the Dim FILE = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\TheGlove\Desktop\Alex's Program\loginfile" & files & ".txt") line you are only reading the last file, as the files variable is just holding the total count of text files. So if you have 4 .txt files in the folder, you will just read loginfile4.txt.

Comment: You have some "magic strings" in your code - e.g. your `filepath` which you set, and then don't reuse when you can  `FILE = ...`. Avoiding this kind of repetition may help in debugging. Especially your `folderpath` where you use the string, and then set it to a variable!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, your code does read all the text files, but keeps overwriting `details.u` and `details.p` with the value retrieved from each file. So, when the loop gets to the last file, those values are what ends up in the `details` object.

I'm assuming that you want to read all the usernames and passwords into a list and check the details in the TextBoxes against that list, so .. Your code should probably be something like the code below (see the code comments for an explanation of some of the differences.

Before we get to the code, can give you a couple of pointers.

Firstly, always try to use names that are meaningful. Defining your structure as `Info` is not as meaningful as it could be. For example, you would be better calling it `UserInfo` and rather than use `P` and `U`, you would be better using `Password` and `UserName`. It may not matter so much right now, but when you start writing larger more complex programs, and have to come back to them in 6 months time to update them, `info.P` or `details.P` aren't as informative as the suggested names.

Secondly, as @ajd mentioned. Don't use magic strings. Create one definition at the beginning of your code which can be used throughout. Again it makes maintenance much easier if you only have to change a string once instead of multiple times, and reduces the chance of mistakes.

Finally, several of the variables you have defined aren't used in your code at all. Again, at this level, it isn't a major issue, but with large programs, you could end up with a bigger memory footprint than you want.

```
Dim username As String
Dim password As String
Dim fileReader As String
Dim folderpath As String = "C:\Users\TheGlove\Desktop\Alex's Program"
Dim files As Integer
Dim filepath As String

Public Structure UserInfo
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Password As String
End Structure

'Change details to a list of info instead of a single instance
Dim userList As New List(Of UserInfo)


Private Sub Btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    'Iterate through the list of details, checking each instance against the textboxes
    For Each tempUserInfo As UserInfo In userList
        If txtusername.Text = tempUserInfo.Name And txtpassword.Text = tempUserInfo.Password Then
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
            frmmenu.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            'This is here, because after your form has opened an closed, the loop
            'that checks usernames and passwords will continue. The line below exits the loop safely
            Exit For
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("wrong")
            txtusername.Clear()
            txtpassword.Clear()
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Btncreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncreate.Click
    frmcreate.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'clear the list of user details otherwise, if the files are loaded a second time,
    'you'll get the same details added again
    userList.Clear()
    'This line replaces several lines in your code that searches the folder for files
    'marching the search pattern
    Dim fileList() As FileInfo = New DirectoryInfo(folderpath).GetFiles("loginfile*.txt")
    For Each fi As FileInfo In fileList
        MsgBox(fi.Name)
        Dim userDetails() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName)
        Dim tempInfo As New UserInfo With {.Name = userDetails(0), .Password = userDetails(1)}
        'An expanded version of the above line is
        'Dim tempInfo As New info
        'tempInfo.U = userDetails(0)
        'tempInfo.P = userDetails(1)
        userList.Add(tempInfo)
    Next
    files = fileList.Count
End Sub
```